# Laravel view not having all properties passed in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-blade

i am facing a issue in passing the values to laravel view
the object passed to view has values

```
 Collection {#270 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#275 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"category_id": 136
      +"service_name": "ServiceName"
      +"service_description": "fgdgfgfdg"
      +"image": null
      +"created_at": "2018-08-17 18:09:16"
      +"updated_at": "2018-08-17 18:09:16"
      +"something": Collection {#101 ▼
        #items: array:2 [▼
          0 => "ABC"
          1 => "DEF"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and the object dd in the view is:-

```
Collection {#270 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#275 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"category_id": 136
      +"service_name": "ServiceName"
      +"service_description": "fgdgfgfdg"
      +"image": null
      +"created_at": "2018-08-17 18:09:16"
      +"updated_at": "2018-08-17 18:09:16"
    }
  ]
}
```

how to get all the values (something property of the passed object).

Comment: We can't  help you without seeing the code

Answer (score -1):

I Solved this problem.
All you need to do is to check your view composer with the same

Comment: that doesn't answer anything ... what does that even mean?